# Change Style of a child element in a CustomControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `CustomTextBox` as follows:

```
<TextBox x:Class="StackOverflow.CustomUserControl.CustomTextBoxView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     x:Name="MainTextBox"
     mc:Ignorable="d">
<TextBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                          Margin="0,0,0,5"
                          Panel.ZIndex="1" />

            <Border CornerRadius="2"
                    Name="BorderToChange"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,3.7"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainTextBox, Path=HintText}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin"
                                Value="0,0,0,3" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                                Value="Bottom" />
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

I use this `CustomTextBox` as follows:

```
<customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView Width="50"
     Height="50"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
     Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Period, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Is there a way I can change the property `BorderThickness` of the `Border` element named "BorderToChange" inside the `ControlTemplate` of my `CustomTextBox` when using it? 
 I have try the following, but it didn't work:

```
<customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView Width="50"
                                        Height="50"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        FontSize="35"
                                        Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Period, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView.Resources>
</customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `{TemplateBinding}` in the template:

```
<Border CornerRadius="2" Name="BorderToChange" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
```

...and specify a default value:

```
<TextBox x:Class="..." BorderThickness="0,0,0,3.7"> ...
```

You can then simply set the `BorderThickness` property of the control to override the default value:

```
<customUserControl:CustomTextBoxView ... BorderThickness="1" ... />
```